# Avoid duplicate objects with the same property with hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the current list with objects with the same property "RED" on the property "COLOR" :

`[ {id:1,name:"John",age:14,color:red}, {{id:2,name:"Michel",age:34,color:blue}}, {{id:3,name:"Yves",age:54,color:red}}]`

I want to use hibernate with criteria to have this result :

`[ {id:1,name:"John",age:14,color:red},{id:2,name:"Michel",age:34,color:blue}]`

It deletes Yves because he has the same property "RED"

Someone could help me ?

My code :

`Criteria criteria = SrvDataAccess.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);`

Thank you.

Comment: So you want distinct results per color, right? Assuming your data is stored in a relational database you'd need to think about how the SQL query for this could look like and from that you should be able to translate to JPA/Hibernate (if that supports everything you'd need). My take would be that you'd need at least one subquery that groups by color and selects 1 element (e.g. `min(id)`) and then the resulting ids are fed into the actual loading query. - Depending on how big the unfiltered data would be it might be easier to just get everything and filter in Java.

Comment: It is possible to make this with criteria ?